# Grails URL Mapping doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I am very new to grails and have customized the `UrlMappings.groovy` file as below:

```
"/"(controller:'sampleGroovy',action:'index').
```

But when I run the application, it still hits the default grails `index.gsp` file instead of the  default controller I configured.

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong here.

Comment: After running my application couple of times and it is now hitting my customized controller instead of the default grails index page. I am really not sure why it did not work before as i did not make any changes except running my application. Is it the issue with embedded Tomcat Container?

Answer (score 2):

Run a `grails clean` before running the application again. It should be your first troubleshooting step when something isn't working as expected and there aren't any other glaring mistakes. That will ensure all files, including UrlMappings.groovy, are recompiled.